# How to copy Azure blobs quickly in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to copy about 1000 blobs at a time from one storage account to another. The size of each blob is roughly between 100 to 1000MB. Each blob is renamed, so I cannot copy the blobs in bulk using a common prefix.

The approach I've taken is to use `BlobClient.start_copy_from_url()` to create an asynchronous copy operation for each blob and wait for them to complete. The problem is that it takes hours to copy the blobs this way. The operations seem to complete in batches of around 6 operations at a time, which makes me think there's something that prevents more from being processed parallel.

In comparison, it takes about 5 minutes for Storage Explorer to copy the same blobs between the storage accounts.

How does Storage Explorer copy files so quickly and is there a way to make my Python script copy blobs faster?

My code is essentially similar this:

```py
active_jobs=[]
for job in pending_jobs: # 1000 pending jobs
     job.target=job.target_client.get_blob_client(job.target_path)           
     source=job.source_client.get_blob_client(job.source_path)
     job.target.start_copy_from_url(source.url)
     active_jobs.append(job)

while active_jobs:
 for job in active_jobs:
   status=job.target.get_blob_properties().copy.status
   if status=="success":
      job.done=True
      print("Job done")
 active_jobs=[job for job in active_jobs if not job.done]
```

Comment: Can you share the code what you have tried?

Comment: @Venkatesan I've added sample code that is similar to the code in my project.

Comment: Storage Explorer copies files faster because it uses the azcopy tool check this learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/477299/… similarly you can use azcopy tool in Python and I don't think client libray copies faster.

Comment: Reference link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/477299/how-to-limit-upload-speed-in-azure-storage-explore

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make my Python script copy blobs faster?

As of now compared to the client library SDK, you can use the **`azcopy tool`** in the Python program to copy faster from source to destination storage account.

You can download the **`AzCopy tool`** from this [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy).
In my environment, I have some files in the source container with (200MB) size in my blob storage.

**Portal:**

[image]

You can use the below Python code to copy from one storage account to another storage account with azcopy tool.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
import time

def copy_blob_with_azcopy(source_account_url, source_sas_token, destination_account_url, destination_sas_token, source_container, source_directory, destination_container):
    source_blob_url = f"{source_account_url}/{source_container}/{source_directory}{source_sas_token}"
    destination_blob_url = f"{destination_account_url}/{destination_container}/{destination_sas_token}"
    
    start_time = time.time()
    azcopy_command = f'azcopy copy "{source_blob_url}" "{destination_blob_url}" --recursive=true'
    subprocess.run(azcopy_command, shell=True)
    end_time = time.time()

    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

    print(f"Blob copied successfully. Elapsed time: {elapsed_time} seconds")


source_account_url = "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net"
source_sas_token = "<Your-SAS-token>"
destination_account_url = "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net"
destination_sas_token = ""<Your-SAS-token>""
source_container = "test"
source_directory = "directory1"
destination_container = "test"

copy_blob_with_azcopy(source_account_url, source_sas_token, destination_account_url, destination_sas_token, source_container, source_directory, destination_container)
```

**Output:**

```
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: azcopy: A newer version 10.21.2 is available to download

INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job d9cee83f-666xxxxa5dea has started
Log file is located at: C:xxxxf-666c-9b45-425a-f2cabf7a5dea.log

100.0 %, 3 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 3 Total,


Job d9cee83f-666c-xxxa summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0669
Number of File Transfers: 3
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 3
Number of Transfers Completed: 3
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 603272234
Final Job Status: Completed

Blob copied successfully. Elapsed time: 7.026703834533691 seconds
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: azcopy is significantly faster than start_copy_from_url(). However, I have to parallelize it using subprocess.Popen(). But why is azcopy faster? What API is it using to copy blobs so much faster?

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-optimize and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-solution-large-dataset-moderate-high-network

Comment: When you use `subprocess.Popen()` to parallelize AzCopy, you are essentially running multiple instances of AzCopy in parallel, each of which can transfer data using multiple threads. This can further improve the performance of data transfer operations and make `AzCopy` even faster than `start_copy_from_url()`.